# xcode Ad-Hoc exporting fail with "Communication Failed"

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to export my app as an Ad-Hoc distribution, this, fails with "Communication Failed", the System log is listed bellow, Not sure if it is related, BUT, I have recently re-newed my dev subscription.

```
 DeveloperPortal: Service 7BF39CD1-3EA0-4D9C-98C2-BBEF4F2F0C93 returned data, but it could not be parsed as a plist:
```

Update - Apple Developer
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        </script>

```
    <section id="content" class="content">
        <header class="header">
            <h1><a href="https://developer.apple.com/"><span class="text-replace">Apple Developer</span></a></h1>
        </header>

        <h1>We'll be back soon.</h1>
    </section>
    <aside class="push"></aside>
</section>

    <footer class="footer">
        <nav class="sosumi">
            <p>Copyright © 2015 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
            <ul class="links">
                <li><a href="http://www.apple.com/legal/terms/site.html" class="first">Terms of Use</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.apple.com/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://developer.apple.com/support/system-status/">System Status</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>



<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('content');
    var width = container.offsetWidth / 2;
    var height = container.offsetHeight;
    container.style.width = (width*2) + 'px';
    container.style.position = 'absolute';
    container.style.left = '50%';
    container.style.top = '50%';
    container.style.marginLeft = -width + 'px';
    container.style.marginTop = -height + 'px';
}

window.onresize = function() {
    width = container.offsetWidth / 2;
    height = container.offsetHeight;

    container.style.marginLeft = -width + 'px';
    container.style.marginTop = -height + 'px';
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is temporary (maybe it's because currently there is the WWDC, and some changes might occurs. If you try to connect to the [member center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action) a message "We'll be back soon" is displayed).

Just wait the end of the WWDC and try again.